# Running a default script in MATLAB whenever an m file execution stops

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to have matlab run a default script whenever the execution of an m file stops? And I do not mean the finish.m that runs when quitting matlab, I want to be able to run a script even when I break the execution of a running script by pressing ctrl+C. Would that be possible?

Comment: If one script calls another, do you want this `scriptfinish` script to be run at the completion of each? or only the final completion?

Comment: Also, what do you want to include in this `scriptfinish`?

Comment: I don't want to specifically call any other script from my own script file. I want to know if it is possible to make another script run, from Matlab, when I stop execution of a running script in any way, perhaps by ending debug session or by pressing ctrl+c while the script is running; something like a destructor being called automatically when a class object destroyed in C. I want to include things in this script that free up memory, such as fclose('all') commands.

Comment: @user13267: Why not write classes or functions instead of scripts then? Feels like this "cleanup" script you want will be used to do cleanup tasks that aren't necessary when you use the right construct...

Comment: @user13267: CTRL+C is used to *terminate hard* all running scripts/functions/etc. It's much like an emergency escape door; it would go against the whole idea of the door if the act of opening the door would set fire to the only non-burning staircase left in a burning building...

Comment: @user13267: Having said that, I see why this could be useful (debugging etc.). You probably can't do it without including a line in each function/script, as there is no programmatic way to talk to the interpreter directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `onCleanup`. This popped into my head when you mentioned Ctrl+C action.

Here is the documentation:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html

Loren has some examples here:
http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/03/10/keeping-things-tidy/

Comment: But this still requires you to call `onCleanup` explicitly in any and all functions...plus, I believe it only activates when the function it's used in goes out of scope, which will never happen in a script or when pressing CTRL+C...

Comment: Also, searching for "CTRL+C" on Loren's blog turns up this: "MATLAB doesn’t have any facility for handling Ctrl-C at the programming level that I know of. I don’t know why you don’t want to use a function, but that solution would be my preferred one, for this, and probably a bunch of other reasons." - Loren

Comment: Well, it is weird but the documentation and Steve Lord's comment here (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/246784) suggest that `onCleanup` should work with Ctrl+C. I do not have the time to try it right now.
Also, writing a function is pretty much always a better idea than writing a script. Maybe @user13267 will decide to go that way?

Comment: I just tested it. Seems like it works with CTRL+C and exiting the debugger, but only in *functions*, **not** in scripts. Still, it's not exactly what the OP wants, as s/he doesn't want to include the line `onCleanup(@()fclose(fid));` in every function/script. Nevertheless: I think this is the closest approximation to what s/he wants, so: +1 :)